# http request, The server returns a 206 status code. Does the browser automatically initiate the next request?

Tags: http, download

The browser initiates an HTTP request to download a large file, the server returns a 206 status code, and the browser will automatically initiate the next request? After many attempts, I found that it was not possible. Is this the correct conclusion?

[image]